Terminology: generalized Laplacian of arbitrary signature
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $E$ any real or complex vector bundle. A linear partial differential operator $D:\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$ is called generalized Laplace operator, if its principal symbol is given by
$$\sigma_{D}(p,\xi)=g^{\sharp}(\xi,\xi)\mathrm{id}_{E}\qquad  \forall(p,\xi)\in T^{\ast}M\tag{1}$$
An important example is the Bochner Laplacian $D=\nabla^{\ast}\nabla$ for any connection $\nabla$ on $E$.
Now, of course, the same definition can also be given for general pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. This does of course change the analytic behavious of these operators and hence, one usually does not call them "Laplacians". In the case of Lorentzian signature $(+,-,\dots,-)$, for example, an operator $D$ with principal symbol (1) is usually called normally hyperbolic, or generalized d'Alembertian/wave operator. An important example is agian provided by the Bochner operator $D=\nabla^{\ast}\nabla$.
Now, I was wondering about the following:

If I want to work with a pseudo-Riemannian manifold of arbitrary signature, is there any accepted terminology for linear operators $D$ with principal symbol (1)?

I have seen at some point a book, if I remember correctly, who was using the terminology "generalized Laplacian" for arbitrary signatures, however, this feels a bit odd, since with "Laplacian" I usually think about an elliptic operator. So, is there any other accepted terminology or at least a nice suggestion?

Dirac introduced  the "Dirac operators"  on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold  corresponding to the relativistic  space-time metric.  They are square roots of the D'Alembertian or the wave operator.  I don't see any problem  extending the  term Laplacian  to any metric.
